# c++ Pointer doesn't stay after leaving scope

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, abstract

I'm having some issues with my pointers and I'm not sure if I'm screwing something up.

```
Class A{
...
}

Class B: public A{
...
X xInfo;
X getX();
}

Class X{
...
A *pointerToAType;
void setPointer(A *point);
}
```

So I have an instantiation of a B object.

I have the code:

```
cout << "True Address: " << &bObj;
cout << "Address one: " << &bObj.getX().pointerToAType;
bObj.getX().setPointer(&bObj);
cout << "Address four: " << &bObj.getX().pointerToAType;
```

With the setPointer code being:

```
X::setPointer(A *pointer){
    cout << "Address two: "<< pointerToAType;
    pointerToAType = pointer;
    cout << "Address three: "<< pointerToAType;
}
```

So the outputs are:
    True Address:0xABCDEF
    Address one: 0
    Address two: 0
    Address three: 0xABCDEF
    Address four: 0

So it appears as if I am successfully updating the pointer inside the method, but as soon as I leave the method, the pointer is nullified.
I am confused as to why this is happening and how I can force the pointer to stay pointed.

I figure that I am passing the location of the address properly, and setting it properly, so it should stay. But I am a bit weak on my pointers.

Minimum Example ?:

```
//main.cpp
main(){
    B bObj;
    cout << "True Address: " << &bObj;
    cout << "Address one: " << &bObj.getX().pointerToAType;
    bObj.getX().setPointer(&bObj);
    cout << "Address four: " << &bObj.getX().pointerToAType;
}

//b.cpp
B::getX(){return xInfo;}

//x.cpp
    X::setPointer(A *pointer){
    cout << "Address two: "<< pointerToAType;
    pointerToAType = pointer;
    cout << "Address three: "<< pointerToAType;
}
```

Comment: Having bits and pieces of code is not helpful. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `&somethingThatIsAPointer` is the *address* of the pointer, not the value of the pointer.

Comment: `getX` returns a copy instead of a reference.

Comment: Here ````&bObj.getX().pointerToAType```` you should not dereference the bObj and ````bObj.getX().pointerToAType```` should print the address.

Comment: Tried to add a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: `&bObj.getX().pointerToAType` should fail to compile. Data member access on an rvalue is still an rvalue and `&` operator cannot be applied to rvalue.  I am VTC as not containing MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in class `B` method `X getX();` return copy of object `X`, which means that each time `bObj.getX()` is called, new `X` object is provided. If something is set in one of those retuned object, it doesn't matter because next time new one is returned with original value.

`X getX()` method need to return reference `X& getX()`

Answer (score 2):

Your `getX` method is returning by value, so you get a copy of the `X` inside `B`. You need to return a reference to the `X`.

```
Class B: public A{
    ...
    X xInfo;
    X& getX();
  // ^ Return reference
}
```

Also, when printing the pointer you should not use the `&`. You want to print the value of the pointer, not the address of the pointer.

```
cout << "Address one: " << bObj.getX().pointerToAType;
                       // ^ No & here
```